# Make div on left side fill screen width based on screen width and with an offset to the center

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I have a parent div with two children inside and I want the first child to go to the left side and the second child should go to the right side. My main problem is they can't start from the exact middle point. They have to start like -100px and +100px from the middle. They should then from that point fill the remaining width of the left or right side of the screen and if the window is resized it should still stick to the exact same position in the middle minus the X Amount of Pixels.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
<div className={classes.backPartDivs}>
  <div />
  <div />
</div>

  backPartDivs: {
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 4,
    left: 0,
    height: 68,
    '& > div': {
      '&:first-child': {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 'calc(-50vw + 50%)',
        height: 68,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        boxShadow: theme.shadows[18],
      },
    },
  },
```

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://codepen.io/raibove/pen/wvgEdyz

Comment: @ShwetaKale yse thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i wrote it in css u can implement it in your app if this is the result you want

```css
.parentDiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 68px;
    background:red;
    display:flex;
    padding:0 100px;
}
.parentDiv div{
width:100%;
height:68px;
margin:0 10px;
background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No this is not right.Check the comment under my answer. That's the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex` to make gaps between nested `div's` and add `margin-left: 100px`.

An example:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}

.container > div:first-of-type {
    width: calc(50% - 50px);
    background-color: orange;
}

/* ----- Flexbox gap: ----- */
.container > * + * {
    margin-left: 100px;
    width: calc(50% - 50px);
    background-color: chocolate;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      left
    </div>
    <div>
      right
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I didn't want. If you resize your screen you'll see that the middle width changes but it has to stay the same!

Comment: @KrisKodira It looks for me that `margin` is always the same. And `margin` always is set to `100px`.

Comment: read my comment again. Try resizing your browser and look at the middle part. While resizing it's moving which I explicitly asked for it not to do. Thank you for your help anyways but it doesn't help.

Comment: @KrisKodira please, see my updated answer. It looks like I understood what you want. Give a try:)

Comment: thanks but I will not change the code since I already have the correct answer as mentioned 2 times already ;)

Comment: @KrisKodira it is ok, I just wanted to understand requirements:)